# How to store any JSON object as a property in a PanacheMongoEntity with MongoDB and Quarkus?

Tags: json, mongodb, quarkus-panache

I wonder how to use a 'any json object' as an entity property. e.h.

```
@MongoEntity
public class ImportEvent extends PanacheMongoEntity {

    public String description;

    public JsonObject customEvent;

}
```

Which type do I need instead of JsonObject?
What I expect for custom event is a random Json object tree.

I set up a Quarkus project with 3.1.0.Final.

Answer (score 0):

After some hours of research:

```
    ...
    public org.bson.Document customEvent;
    ...
```

does the trick.